# Rails Bootstrap X-editable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, x-editable

I've got Bootstrap x-editable working in my Rails app for text and numbers.
But, I haven't been able to get a date to work.

I'm using gem 'bootstrap-editable-rails'.

This is the view code:

```
<a href="#" class="xeditable_date" data-type="date" data-pk="1" data-resource="task" data-name="eststartdate" data-url="/tasks/<%= task.id %>" >
<%= task.eststartdate %>
</a>
```

This is the coffee script:

```
$(".xeditable_date").editable
  placement: 'bottom'
  format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
  datepicker:
    weekStart: 1
```

Console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'parseFormat' of undefined   application.js:33351
$.extend.initPicker application.js:33351
Date application.js:33324
$.fn.editableutils.createInput application.js:30030
Editable.init application.js:30580
Editable application.js:30566
(anonymous function) application.js:31087
jQuery.extend.each application.js:649
jQuery.fn.jQuery.each application.js:271
$.fn.editable application.js:31081
(anonymous function) application.js:56013
fire application.js:1038
self.fireWith application.js:1149
jQuery.extend.ready application.js:434
completed application.js:104
```

I'm using PG and the `eststartdate` is type date.  So, I believe the date format 'yyyy-mm-dd' is correct.  An example of the field displays as `2013-08-26`.

Thanks for the help!

UPDATE1

I thought I would try something different.  But, it displays a text field and not the date picker:

View code:

```
<a href="#" class="xeditable datepicker" data-type="text" data-pk="1" data-resource="task" data-name="eststartdate" data-url="/tasks/<%= task.id %>" >
<%= task.eststartdate ? task.eststartdate : "Select Date" %>
</a>
```

Coffeescript:

```
$(".xeditable").editable
  placement: 'bottom'
```

Comment: What about errors in browser console?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'parseFormat' of undefined $.extend.initPicker application.js:33351
Date

Comment: Looks like smth is wrong with date format. Anyway, you found why it's not working)))